# Key mapping (grave accent) and encoding issue in .vimrc

Tags: vim, encoding

I have an odd problem with mapping in Vim. I am using an Azerty keyboard.

In my .vimrc, I have the following command to quickly move between paragraphs.:

```
nnoremap _ {
vnoremap _ {

nnoremap è }
vnoremap è }
```

However, the second mapping using `è` is not taken into account.

After startup, if I check the mapping, I got something for `:verbose map _` but nothing for `:verbose map è`.

Worse, if I actually type `nnoremap è }`in runtime, the mapping is correctly registered.

I think this is an encoding issue, but I don't manage to find a work around.

I am using Vim 7.3 on Debian Lenny.

I am using the same .vimrc on WinXP, and it works there : the only difference is that on WinXP I am using `set encoding=latin1` beforehand, while on Debian, I have not changed the default encoding which is `utf-8`

So basically, my question becomes why it works with encoding equals to `latin1` and not `utf-8`  Does it have something to do with `è` being encoded in multiple bytes in utf-8 ?

Comment: Strange, I have a command mapped to `é` which works both on Mac and Linux both with `set encoding=utf8` (they use the same vimrc). What is the encoding of your vimrc?

Comment: That was the issue, the .vimrc was encoded in latin1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the `.vimrc` file encoding is not correct.

You can see it using `set fileencoding`, and change it using `:w ++enc=utf-8` or `:w ++enc=iso-8859-1`.

Comment: That is the correct answer ! The fileencoding of the .vimrc file was "latin1" and did not match the "encoding" setting which was utf-8. So saving .vimrc with fileencoding=utf-8 fixed the issue !

Comment: @XavierT. It is also a good idea to add `scriptencoding utf-8` to the top of your vimrc, so that it won’t depend on `&encoding` option value (with different `&encoding` file contents will just be recoded in this case). By the way, why do you ever need `&encoding≠'utf-8'`?

Comment: @Zyx : Good question, I don't exactly know why I was still using latin1 on WinXP. I think it stems from the fact that the starting point for my `.vimrc` a few years ago was not in utf-8. Now, since I have rewritten it multiple times, it does not really make any sense to keep an encoding different than utf-8